# URL with trailing slash 404, appending index.php or ?someString works

Tags: apache-2.2, mod-rewrite, cache

Recently I've encountered an issue where some pages 404 when accessed via their cruftless paths.

The same pages work when a query string, like `?1234` or `index.php` is appended to the path.

Example:

http://pagesofinterest.net/code/plugins/code-complete/ - Fail

http://pagesofinterest.net/code/plugins/code-complete/?123 - Success

http://pagesofinterest.net/code/plugins/code-complete/index.php - Success

I'm not sure if this is a mod_rewrite or a caching issue.

Here is the content of my .htaccess file:

```
# Use PHP5.3 Single php.ini as default
AddHandler application/x-httpd-php53 .php

#ExpiresDefault A0
Header set Cache-Control "no-store, no-cache, must-revalidate, max-age=0"
Header set Pragma "no-cache"

DirectoryIndex index.php index.html

RewriteEngine on

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www.pagesofinterest.net [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://pagesofinterest.net/$1 [R=301,NC] 

# Error documents
ErrorDocument 404 /404.php
ErrorDocument 403 /404.php
ErrorDocument 500 /500.php

# compress a few file extensions
AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE text/plain
AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE text/xml
AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE application/xhtml+xml
AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE text/css
AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE application/xml
AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE application/rss+xml
AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE application/atom_xml
AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE application/x-javascript
AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE text/html

BrowserMatch ^Mozilla/4 gzip-only-text/html
BrowserMatch ^Mozilla/4.0[678] no-gzip
BrowserMatch ^MSIE !no-gzip !gzip-only-text/html

<IfModule mod_expires.c>
    # explicitly disable caching for scripts and other dynamic files
    <FilesMatch "\.(pl|php|cgi|spl|scgi|fcgi)$">
        Header unset Cache-Control
    </FilesMatch>
</IfModule>

Redirect /mikes http://pagesofinterest.net/blog/
Redirect /code-of-interest http://pagesofinterest.net/code

# Redirect all old photo pages to the tiny new one
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/photos/[a-z\/]+$
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://pagesofinterest.net/photos/ [R=301,L]
```

Comment: Are there any errors generated in Apache's error log?  You may also want to turn on the mod_rewrite log--its possible one of your rules--or a global rule--is affecting what's happening.

Answer (score 1):

This look kind of weird, we would need the errors generated from the rewrite module log (see https://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_rewrite.html for additional info how to enable rewritelog directive). The problem look like restricted to your code-complete page as all the accessible link from the menu does give valid URL/pages.

The 'quick-fix/hack' way would be to add redirects for that page. I do NOT advocate that way, but sometimes, we just want it to work...

```
Redirect /code/plugins/code-complete /code/plugins/code-complete/index.php
Redirect /code/plugins/code-complete/ /code/plugins/code-complete/index.php
```

Also, as a side-note, you are losing the "/" in the original query. I would change the

```
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://pagesofinterest.net/$1 [R=301,NC]
```

for

```
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://pagesofinterest.net$1 [R=301,NC]
```